# Maven: Not copying files from src/main/resources to the classpath root - Executable Jar

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, jar, executable

I am building an executable jar with Maven using the Assembly plugin. I have a resource file(.xml) which is placed at src/main/resources. When I build the executable jar, the file is not getting copied into the jar - Checked by unpacking the jar.

Here is my pom.xml:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>package-jar-with-dependencies</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>single</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
                <descriptorRefs>
                    <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                </descriptorRefs>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                        <mainClass>xx.com.xxx.xxxx.xx.xxxx.InterfaceRunner</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                    <manifestEntries>
                        <Class-Path>.</Class-Path>
                    </manifestEntries>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

I am trying to call the following resource which is kept under src/main/resources:

```
reader = Resources.getResourceAsReader("mybatis-configuration.xml");
```

Getting the following exception while executing `java -jar InterfaceRunner.jar`

```
Exception caught while reading or parsing the mybatis config xml :java.io.IOException: Could not find resource mybatis-configuration.xml
    at org.apache.ibatis.io.Resources.getResourceAsStream(Resources.java:108)
    at org.apache.ibatis.io.Resources.getResourceAsStream(Resources.java:95)
    at org.apache.ibatis.io.Resources.getResourceAsReader(Resources.java:153)
```

Has anyone faced a similar issue before? Looking for your help, Maven gurus..

Comment: `mvn clean package` check the build jar for the resources, there or not?

Answer (score 0):

You can try replacing your `Configuration` as follows;

```
<configuration>
        <archive>
                <manifest>
                        <mainClass>xx.com.xxx.xxxx.xx.xxxx.InterfaceRunner</mainClass>
                </manifest>
        </archive>
        <descriptorRefs>
            <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
        </descriptorRefs>
    <finalName>InterfaceRunner</finalName>
</configuration>
```

And then

```
mvn package
```

Comment: Not sure if this is the cause of the problem:<manifestEntries>
                        <Class-Path>.</Class-Path>
                    </manifestEntries>

Comment: I will need the Classpath to be set to the root, for accessing some properties files externally

Answer (score 0):

By default, `maven-assembly-plugin` makes TWO jars, not one (with phase package). Make sure you are running the one called `<artifactid>-<version>-jar-with-dependencies.jar`

If this is not the problem, are you doing anything weird in your pom here:

```
<build>
    <resources>
        <resource>
             <targetPath><!-- here?? --></targetPath>
        </resource>
    </resources>
    <!-- etc. -->
</build>
```

Comment: I am using Spring Tool Suite(STS) to build using Maven and I am using maven install command. There is only one jar created though in the target location by the name - <artifactid>-<version>.jar

Comment: I am also not setting anything inside the <resources> tag